# Displaying data from MySQL into TextView in Android Studio

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, xampp

I want to display data from MySQL into Android using TextView,, but when I'm running the app, its goes force stop itself.

Can someone help me how to fix it? any idea would be nice.

**`dbconfig.php`**:

```html
<?php

//This script is designed by Android-Examples.com
//Define your host here.
$servername = "localhost";
//Define your database username here.
$username = "root";
//Define your database password here.
$password = "";
//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "u727224026_demo";

?>
```

**`send_data.php`**

```html
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TextViewTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $json = json_encode($row);


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

**`MainActivity.java`**

```js
package flix.yudi.kuesioner2;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview;
    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    Context context;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

            }
        });
    }


    private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;


        public GetTextViewData(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.100.6/a_test/send-data.php");

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);



            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            try {
                textview.setText(json.getString("ServerData"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Hiding progress bar after done loading TextView.
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }


}
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.jsonparsingfromurltextview_android_examples.com.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView Static Text Before Load"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="Click Here to Load TextView data dynamically from MySQL Database Online Using JSON Parsing" />
```

logcat error notif

> 10-04 15:41:44.516 22210-22210/flix.yudi.kuesioner2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: flix.yudi.kuesioner2, PID: 22210
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at flix.yudi.kuesioner2.MainActivity$GetTextViewData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:114)
>                                                                             at flix.yudi.kuesioner2.MainActivity$GetTextViewData.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:60)
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                             at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I tried to find how to fix it, but still nothing,
please help me.

ADDITIONAL INFO RESPONSE FROM HTTP_REQUESTER:

[image]

Comment: thanks for help me making the post more simple,

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this line new

`new GetTextViewData(context).execute();`

Context is a pointer but referring to nothing... This causing  a null pointer exception.

As you are passing context use:

`new GetTextViewData(this).execute();`

Hope this helps.